# filter after nested query and map the result in elasticsearch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-aggregation

This is the Index data where payload is the list containing the data

```
{
      "payload": [
        {
          "category": "GENRE",
          "value": "Comedy"
        },
        {
          "category": "DATE",
          "value": "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "category": "COLOUR",
          "value": "Red"
        },
        {
          "category": "COLOUR",
          "value": "Green"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to search the Query
**category=COLOUR&where=(payload.category:GENRE AND payload.value:comedy)**

Below I created the Query where I have done the part of (payload.category:GENRE AND payload.value:comedy). But now I want to filter the Result  and map it to category of category=COLOUR

```
GET /dev_video_clip_59f977063265a634a8ae15bf/_search
{
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "payload",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "payload.category": "ASSET"
                          
                        }
                       
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "payload.value": "BOSE"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "payload.category": "ASSET"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "payload.value": "Contigo"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In the end, the want the result of category = color , but the payload should contain the category as genre and value as comedy in the list
After I run this query I want
category=COLOUR&where=(payload.category:GENRE AND payload.value:comedy)

This should be the result now I have run the and query and filtered the colour and mapped only colour value

```
{
  "values": [
    "Red",
    Green
  ]
}
```

Comment: your data structure is quite convoluted. Any reason for having a key-value field like "payload" instead of dedicated 1st-level fields for "genre", "date", "colour", etc? That would simplify greatly your problem

Comment: It was designed by the previous team, so now every functionality is on that DS,